# With `strictNullChecks` enabled, what is the difference between the `void` type and `undefined` literal type?

Tags: typescript, types, undefined, void

With `strictNullChecks` enabled:

```
(u: undefined, v: void, n: null) => {
  v = u;
  u = v; // type error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
  v = n; // type error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void'
}
```

I presume there must be some value of type `void` that is not of type `undefined`, but with `strictNullChecks` enabled I'm unaware of any. For which values is this true?

Comment: I'd love to know where you are using void or undefined as a type, I only use it for return types, or implementing a generic class that doesn't really need a type, that is `my event: Event<void>` for an event of no type

Comment: Strange, the doc says: **Declaring variables of type void is not useful because you can only assign undefined or null to them:**

Comment: @Fals Why is that strange?

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm asking because I want to have an exact understanding of the type system, and this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: On a related note, I find it odd that `(a: any, v: void) => { v = a; a = v; }` doesn't throw any errors when `strictNullChecks` is enabled. [According to the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void), if `void` is the opposite of `any`, then why would they both be assignable to each other... Interesting question! It doesn't really make much sense to me either.

Comment: `void` isn't the opposite of `any`, that much is clear. `any` really isn't a type at all, it's more like a pragma to turn off type checking. The main reason I'm asking this question is because I want to determine what is the "top" of TypeScript's type lattice, the type of all values, but with which nothing useful can be done. The bottom is `never`, so what's `always`? As best I can tell it's `type always = {} | void | null`, but it seems like `{} | undefined | null` should work just as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For which values is this true?

The only way to obtain a value of type `void` is to invoke a `void`-returning function:

```
function f() { }
let x = f();
```

Note that because it's legal to alias a non-`void`-returning function through a variable of type `() => void`, the `void` value obtained this way *might not* actually be the value `undefined`, hence the subtype relationship.

Comment: Ah, the fact that `() => void` is a supertype of `() => T` for all `T` makes sense as the reason for this. Interesting quirk of the type system.

Answer (score 2):

There's only 2 types that you can assign to `void`: `undefined` and `null`. Void as the name say, is the opposite of anything, the nothing, the absence of having a type.

[TypeScript Handbook:Basic Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: That would make sense since `null` and `undefined` are loosely equal (==) to each other (coercable to same type) but not anything else.

Comment: I updated the question... is there another non-`undefined` value of type `void` when `strictNullChecks` is enabled?

Comment: @TomCrockett Ryan's answers completes mine!